# IMAP connection error with gmail just after using SMTP

Tags: java, groovy, smtp, gmail, imap

Here is my code. The code is in groovy.

```
    //send email
    def host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    def props = new Properties()
    props.put "mail.smtps.auth", "true"
    def session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
    def msg = new MimeMessage(session)
    msg.setSubject subject
    msg.setText messageText
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to, to))
    def transport = session.getTransport "smtps"
    transport.connect(host, username, password)
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients())
    transport.close()

    //fetch emails
    def host = "imap.gmail.com"
    def port = "993"

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap")
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host)
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", port)
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    def session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
    def store = session.getStore("imap")

    store.connect(host, username, password)

    def inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX")
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)

    def messages = inbox.getMessages()
```

This code fails while connecting imap store.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Cannot connect to IMAP server
```

If I skip sending email using smtp, the fetching part works. Both sending and fetching mails uses same gmail account. I guess there can be some problem with session or gmail limits. The sending email is working as well.